# How to escape HTML attribute from JSON string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am wondering how can I escape HTML attribute from JSON string using PHP.
Here is an example:

I want to change this (It's a broken JSON that was fetched from database, I need to fix it):

```
{"name":"column","content":"<h3 class="open-sans" style="font-size: 2em; line-height:2em;" >FORM TITLE</h3>" }
```

to this (single quote for attributes):

```
{"name":"column","content":"<h3 class='open-sans' style='font-size: 2em; line-height:2em;' >FORM TITLE</h3>" }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

## Update:

If found the solution:

```
preg_replace('/="(.*?)"/s', '=\'$1\'', $string, -1);
```

Comment: How do you get this json object?

Comment: Create proper JSON in the first place, don't try to parse broken JSON.

Comment: The proper answer is to properly JSON escape the HTML string when creating the JSON, which should result in `"<h3 class=\"...\"..."`. You basically get this behaviour for free if you use any standard JSON encoder instead of cobbling this together by hand.

Comment: This json string is fetch from database and is kinda broken, I need to fix this broken string by preg_replace or any other filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `json_encode`. Pass your array into that & rest will be taken care automatically.
Regular expression:

```
preg_replace('/="(.*?)"/s', '=\'$1\'', $string, -1);
```

Comment: I know about that function, It's a broken json string which is saved in database, I need to fix it.

Comment: You should have taken care while saving into DB.

Comment: Now either you should write a regular expression or do it manually.